# AppVeyor doesn't update GitHub pull request with the build status

Tags: github, build, continuous-integration, pull-request, appveyor

I have a project on GitHub that is hooked with AppVeyor for continuous integration. AppVeyor is supposed to post status updates to pull requests, as in [this example](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker/pull/513). However, it doesn't work for my project. AppVeyor builds are correctly triggered, but pull requests don't show the status indicators.

How can I make it work? Is there a specific way to set up the AppVeyor project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, looks like it was just an authorization problem. The project was initially under my own account, but I recently transferred it to an organization. I had to revoke AppVeyor access and grant it again, with access to the organization.

Comment: I have this problem, but I don't understand where you revoked and regranted access in github's UI. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @thakis, it's in the *Account settings* page (accessible from the account menu)